# wrong routing with koa-router in koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, frameworks, koa

I am learning Koa, with basic exercise, but i can´t achieve implement a simple routing, with the code that i got from this [page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/koajs/koajs_routing.htm), and this is what i did:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router'); //require it
var app = new koa();
var ro = router();
//and we'll set up 2 routes, for our index and about me pages
ro.get('/hello', getMessage);

function *getMessage() {
    this.body = "Hello world!";
 };
app.use(ro.routes());
app.listen(8008);
console.log('Koa listening on port 8008');
```

i did´t get any specific error, because the app run with the command `node index.js`, but i can see any print in the page that i routed.

[image]

and i only have 1 file in my folder myproyectoks, and it is index.js, and that's the file that i'm working.

[image]

any information that you need pls ask me :D, because i could be forgot something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is out-of-date - Koa middleware is promise-based and generator functions will no longer work directly. The [router documentation](https://github.com/koajs/router/blob/HEAD/API.md) suggests the following form:

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('@koa/router')

const router = new Router()
router.get(
    '/hello', 
    ctx => ctx.body = 'Hello world!'
)

const app = new Koa()
app.use(router.routes())

app.listen(8008)
```

To note the other differences, the router module is a class that requires instantiation and the context is passed as an argument to the request handler.